# Обработка сложного jsonb поля

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

У меня есть таблица с двумя колонками

```
Some Table
- id int
- data jsonb
```

Одна строка может выглядить вот так

```
id      jsonb
111     {"1": {"b": 11}, "2":{"b":22}}
```

Нужно написать запрос так, чтобы он выводил id записи и сумму значений с ключом b

```
id  sum
111 33
```

Копал в строну jsonpath чтобы адресоваться на значение этого поля, но не вышло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, 
   (select sum((v->>'b')::int) from jsonb_each(data) as j(k,v)) 
from tablename
```